# Postgresql create trigger deferrable not working with referencing new table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to create a statement-level trigger that is deferred, and also reference the new transition table

So far I have tried this (on table rows):

```sql
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER check_rows
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
ON rows 
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS newtable 
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED 
FOR EACH STATEMENT 
EXECUTE FUNCTION check_rows();
```

But I'm getting the error `syntax error at or near "REFERENCING"`

What are my eyes missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFERRABLE` must be *before* `REFERENCING`, but that is academic. As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) says,

> The `REFERENCING` option enables collection of *transition relations*, which are row sets that include all of the rows inserted, deleted, or modified by the current SQL statement. [...] This option is only allowed for an AFTER trigger that is not a constraint trigger [...]

So you cannot use transition tables in a constraint trigger.

Comment: Ah cool thank you, but apparently I cannot use deferrable in a statement-level trigger? is that correct? cause I get `syntax error at or near "DEFERRABLE"`

Comment: The syntax error is because of the bad position of the clause in the statement. You can use deferrable *only* in statement level `AFTER` triggers defined with the `CONSTRAINT` clause.

Comment: So currently there is no way to actually use transition tables in a deferrable statement-level trigger

Comment: I mean create a trigger that runs after transactions while using transition tables, that's not possible

Comment: Right. I thought that my answer made that clear.